# How to use custom page type class for current document

Tags: c#, kentico

Currently, I have several custom page types within the CMS. In order to have type safety when working with documents, I used built-in code generator to create classes for each page type. For example, I have a page type called Whitepaper and the Kentico code generator generated two classes:

```cs
public partial class Whitepaper : TreeNode { }

public partial class WhitepaperProvider { }
```

These classes work great if I'm directly querying for specific documents using the provider such as:

```cs
WhitepaperProvider.GetWhitepapers().TopN(10);
```

However, I want to be able to use the `Whitepaper` class for the current document without having to re-query for the document using the `WhitepaperProvider`. In this case I have a custom page template for Whitepapers and in the code behind I want to be able to use the custom class for it:

```cs
// This is what I'm using
TreeNode currentDocument = DocumentContext.CurrentDocument;
var summary = currentDocument.GetStringValue("Summary", string.Empty);

// This is what I'd like to use, because I know the template is for whitepapers
Whitepaper currentWhitepaperDocument = // what goes here?
summary = currentWhitepaperDocument.Summary;
```

How do I use my custom page type class for the current document?

---

**UPDATE**

As the answer mentions using `as` works as long as a class has been registered for the current page type. I didn't expect this to work because I assumed DocumentContext.CurrentDocument always returned a TreeNode (thus you'd have a contravariance problem); if there is a class registered for the page type it will return an instance that class instead thus allowing you to use `as`.

Comment: Have you tried to cast current document as your custom class?: Whitepaper currentWhitepaperDocument = DocumentContext.CurrentDocument as Whitepaper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as...

```
var stronglyTyped = DocumentContext.CurrentDocument as Whitepaper
```

...as long as you've registered your Whitepaper class as a document type by using the `DocumentType` attribute on `CMSModuleLoader` e.g.:

```
[DocumentType("WhitepaperClassName", typeof(Namespace.To.Whitepaper))]
```

This is a good blog post about wiring up strongly typed page type objects: http://johnnycode.com/2013/07/15/using-strongly-typed-custom-document-type-classes/

Comment: This definitely works however I didn't expect it to. I assumed DocumentContext.CurrentDocument always returned a TreeNode but if there's a class registered for the page type is will return that class automatically instead. I'll update my post, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can extend your partial class (do not modify the generated file, create a partial for original), example:

```
public partial class Whitepaper
{
    public Whitepaper CreateFromNode(TreeNode node)
    {
        //You should choose all necessary params in CopyNodeDataSettings contructor
        node.CopyDataTo(this, new CopyNodeDataSettings());
        //You should populate custom properties in method above.
        //this.Status = ValidationHelper.GetString(node["Status"], "");
        return this;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
new Whitepaper().CreateFromNode(DocumentContext.CurrentDocument)
```